# how to find the longest_word by using searching loop

Tags: python, list, file, dictionary, for-loop

Write a function longest_word that asks the user for words and returns the longest word entered by the user. It should stop when the user hits return without typing a word. If multiple words have the same maximum length, return the first word entered by the user. If the user quits before entering any words, return “No words were entered”. This function should use a searching loop.

(Hint: remember that the len function returns the length of a string.)

Comment: Let me point out, if all you want to know is "which files contain any of the words in "terms.txt", you can do that with the command-line `grep` tool.  No programming is required.

Answer (score 0):

**Takes `list of files` and a next  and checks if the words in `file` appear in those files.**

#### Code:

```py
def list_search_dictionary(fname, listfname):
    for search in listfname:
        with open(fname,'r') as f1:
            with open(search,'r') as f2:

                #splits word by word
                All = f2.read().split()
                formater = lambda x:x.strip().lower()

                #formats each element
                All = list(map(formater,All))
                for word in f1:
                    word = formater(word)
                    if word in All:
                        print(f'Found: {word}')
```

##### Using your functions:

***Change your function to:***

```
def my_search_dictionary(search_dic, fname):
    # read the file
    infile = open(fname,"r")

    # look for each line in the file
    for line in infile:
            
        # remove the string at the end of the line
        line_strip = line.strip()
        
        # lowercase
        line_lower = line_strip.lower()
        # i love dogs
        # more than hotdogs
        
        # split " " in the line and make them in the list
        line_split = line_lower.split(" ")
        # ["i"," love dogs"]
        # ["more", " than", " hotdogs"]
        
        # look for each search term in the line_split
        for word in line_split:
            
            # check if every word in the line 
            for key in search_dic:
                
                if word == key:
                    search_dic[key] += [fname]

    infile.close()
```

***The third function would be:***

```py
def list_search_dictionary(fname, listfname):
    search_dic = key_emptylist(fname)
    for file in listfname:
        search_dic = my_search_dictonary(search_dic,file)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What if I want to call back the first and the second function in the third function?

Comment: ***PS: Accept and upvote*** the answer if it answers your question.